# How can I drag and drop a xaml activity to a WF4 rehosted designer?

Tags: .net, wpf, drag-and-drop, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

I understand that the `WorkflowDesigner` can receive a dragged item in several ways, for example:

- By dragging an item from the toolbox and dropping it on the designer: an empty activity of that type will be inserted on the designer at the drop location.
- One can also drag an activity from the designer and drop it on another location in the designer, the dragged activity will be inserted at the drop location as well.

Is it possible that similar to these two drag and drop mechanism, I can drag a xaml activity to the designer? What I have in mind is this,

Let's say you have a `ListView` containing several xaml files. I want to be able to drag one of the `ListView` items (ie one of the xaml files), and when I drag it over the designer it will act as if I drag something from the toolbox (except the activity will be supplied from the xaml). I know I can create a runtime `Activity` from the file by using `ActivityXamlServices.Load(filename)`, and I want this activity to be inserted at the drop location. But how to tell the application to understand this when I drag and drop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given `WorkflowDesigner designer`, `Activity activity`, and drag source `dataSource`, use this code (credits to [tilovell](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tilovell/archive/2010/01/06/freeform-custom-activity-designers-using-icompositeview-part-4.aspx))

```
ModelItem mi = designer.Context.Services.GetService<ModelTreeManager>()
    .CreateModelItem(null, activity);
DataObject data = new DataObject(DragDropHelper.ModelItemDataFormat, mi);
DragDrop.DoDragDrop(dataSource, data, DragDropEffects.Copy);
```

The application will go into drag and drop mode. The designer will receive the drop as an Activity.

Comment: So what is activity here? A compiled activity type, something loaded with ActivityXamlServices or something else altogether. And if it isn't a compiled activity what is the generated xaml like when you save the workflow?

Comment: something loaded with ActivityXamlServices.

Comment: `Activity activity = ActivityXamlServices.Load(filename);`

Comment: Interesting, normally XAML elements refer to .NET types but ActivityXamlServices.Load() doesn't return a type or an instance of something that exists as a type. Is the complete activity tree loaded with ActivityXamlServices.Load() inserted into the final XAML?

Comment: yes. The behaviour is exactly the same as if I dragged a dynamic activity to that spot

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this because activities added to a workflow need to be compiled. When you create a XAML activity and compile your project in VS2010 the resulting compiled activity type is added to the toolbox, not a reference to the XAML file you created.

Comment: are you sure? runtime (non-compiled) activities can be added for example when pasting or drag and dropping another activity to the designer.

Comment: looking at [this blogpost](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tilovell/archive/2010/01/06/freeform-custom-activity-designers-using-icompositeview-part-4.aspx) is it possible to do that using DragDrop.DoDragDrop? what would be the DataObject?

Comment: I am referring to Nick's comment in the comment section

Comment: It should be a fully qualified type name so Type.GetType() return the type. Meaning the activity should be a .NET type and therefore compiled.